# setup.py install os dependency

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pypi, distutils

I want to make a distributable package.
And my package depends on some OS package

Here what I want to install:

```
def install_libmagic():
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        subprocess.run(['brew', 'install', 'libmagic'])
    elif sys.platform == 'linux':
        subprocess.run(['apt-get', 'update'])
        subprocess.run(['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'libmagic1'])
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Unknown system: {sys.platform}, can not install libmagic')
```

I want this code to be executed only when smb call:
`pip install mypacakge`

I don't want it to be executed when I run: `python setup.py bdist_wheel`

**How can I achieve this?**

I tried this:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=install_libmagic(),
)
```

Also tried to override install command:

```
from setuptools.command.install import install

class MyInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        install_libmagic()
        install.run(self)
setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'install': MyInstall}
)
```

But the function was executed on `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, which is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: `setup.py` usually isn't run as root.

Comment: ...if you want to install OS packages, have you considered making a OS package _for your Python module_? Then someone installing _your_ package with `apt` will get the others as dependencies.

Comment: (Mind, folks using [Nix](https://nixos.org/) can have cross-language dependency chains without trouble, but that's very much its own thing).

Comment: `usually isn't run as root` well, that's the point, didn't thought about it. My package is for local index only (for company purposes), so I know that it's basically is launched by root.

Comment: `apt` package is an interesting option, haven't tried it before, maybe I should now:)

Comment: See [`Python/LibraryStyleGuide`](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide?action=show&redirect=Python%2FPackaging) or the Debian wiki for guidance on making dpkg packages you can install with apt (unless you're using apt4rpm or similar, in which case you need to build a spec file -- which is arguably easier).

Comment: I hope there are still options to do this with `python setup.py bdist_wheell` and `pip install`, I just  haven't digged enough to find the answer:)

Comment: Gotcha. If you're guaranteed your `pip install` will happen is root, I'm quite certain there are options, but it's not a usage mode I'm willing to support -- even if I write up an answer for you to use internally, someone else is going to try to use it for a package they're publishing to the public.

Comment: oh, you really know the answer?) The answer can be written with a disclaimer "Do not do this for public package" or just be written in comments. I spent hours googling for it:)

Comment: See https://github.com/mschwager/0wned

Comment: thanks man, I realised that it's possible through installation of the source code (because setup.py is launched) but it's not possible through wheel installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing up the behaviors of built distributions (wheels) and source distributions.

If your goal is run some subprocesses at *install* time, then you can't do this with a built distribution. A built distribution executes no Python code at install time. It only executes `setup.py` at *build* time, which is why you're seeing your functions executed when you call `python setup.py bdist_wheel`.

On the other hand, a source distribution (`python setup.py sdist`) *does* execute the `setup.py` file at both build time and install time (roughly the same as `python setup.py install`) and would give you the behavior you're looking for.

However, as the comments have already mentioned, this is going to be very fragile and not very user-friendly or portable. What you're describing is really a distro/OS package that contains some Python module, and you'd probably be better off with that instead.

Comment: Thanks man. I realised that it is not possible through python wheels, but is possible through installation of the source code.

Comment: Marking question as resolved. If you want to achieve what I wanted, just override install command`cmdclass={'install': PostInstallCommand}` upload your code to the repository, and install it with smth like `git+https://github.com/<your_project>/<your_repo>.git@<branch>`